# swift Dictionary problem where it needs to be ordered by the key

Tags: swift, ordereddictionary

I have an issue where I am able to sort the dictionary however the result is weird.

```
  class MyModel {
     var dict = [Date: Int]()
    ...
  }
  let sortDict = dict.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
      return first.key > second.key
    }
    dictDatePlacesCount = sortDict[0]
```

The issue is that I get a syntax error

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<Date, Int>.Element' (aka '(key: Date, value: Int)') to type '[Date : Int]'
```

The question is that I cannot create a custom Dictionary with this rule of sorting in descending order with the Date?

I did explore and found OrderedDictionary but it seems like an external package?

Comment: seems that `dictDatePlacesCount` is declared as a dictionary `[Date: Int]` instead of a dictionary element (key value pair) `(Date, Int)`

Comment: Yes, `OrderedDictionary` is from an external package called Swift Collections. You should definitely be using something like that if you truly want a `Dictionary` as your result type. The `sorted` function that you're trying to call right now doesn't return a `Dictionary`, it returns an `Array` with a tuple representing the `keys` and `values`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jnpdx says, the Dictionary method `sorted()` returns an array of tuples of type `(Key, Value)` (So `(Date, Int)` in your case.)

The Swift standard library doesn't have an ordered dictionary. Again, as mentioned by jnpx, there are frameworks/libraries like the official [Swift Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) that offer ordered dictionaries. You might want to use one of those.

Alternatively, you could sort the keys from your dictionary and use those to index into your contents.

Comment: In fairness, Swift Collections isn't really "third party." It's "staging ground for stdlib." It doesn't make all the ABI promises of stdlib, but it's not just some random code on GitHub.

Comment: I edit the phrasing slightly, because the statement "There is no such thing as a sorted dictionary in Swift" is wrong as stated, because the official Swift Collections pacakge certainly counts as being "in swift".

Comment: Better choice of words. Thanks.